How to serve acme-challenge file dynamically with Jester REST API?
Is it possible to dynamically serve the acme challenge file generated and required by certbot with rest api by jester with nim lang?
I have this code
get "/.well-known/acme-challenge/@challenge":
      writeFile(getCurrentDir() / @"challenge", @"challenge")
      sendFile getCurrentDir() / @"challenge"

which works if used with browser but doesn’t work with certbot.

I don't think it's possible because the contents are not exactly the same as the token passed in the url. Even if it were possible you don't want to do that since it sounds like your domain would accept all challenges made by any hacker making a request for your domain.
Use the available clients https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/
